# How to pass data from app.post to app.get?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to show webpage to users at the route app.get(/:transactionid) with the text telling them "Please wait, your file is processing"

And after file processing is finished (could take around 5-10 seconds) then change that text to "Your file is ready, download here"

But I don't really know how to pass variable from app.post to app.get.
The variable is just aws-s3 download link (if that matters).

I have 2 routes like so:

```
app.get('/:transactionid', async (req,res)=>{
     res.render('purchase')
})

app.post('/:transactionid', async (req,res)=>{
 // some file processing and uploading to aws-s3
     const url = s3url;
     res.render('purchase',{link:url})
})
```

and in the ejs view I have:

```
<body>
    <% if(link) { %>
        Your file is ready <a href="<%= link %>"><div class="inline text-blue-600">Download here </div></a>
    <% } else { %>
    <div class="text-red-500">Please wait, your file is processing</div>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

But the `res.render('purchase',{link:url})` in `app.post` won't update the text in the browser. I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I think I should send the url from app.post to app.get?

EDIT:
Here are some snippets of what it looks like uploading and inserting it into database

```
var params = {
    Bucket: 'xxxxxxx', 
    Key: decodeURIComponent(awskey), 
    Body: buff };

// upload to s3
var uploadfile = s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  if(err) {console.log(err);}
});

// turn it into promise
var promise = uploadfile.promise();
promise.then( function(data){
  
  pool.query(`
  INSERT INTO transactions (transactionid, s3url)
  VALUES ($1, $2)
  `, [transactionid, data.Location], (err, results) => { // data.Location is the s3 url
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }
      
  });
})
```

Comment: Are you using javascript/AJAX to do the submit/upload? If so you need to use the callback of that request to update your html. If it's an actual form submit then I don't see any issues. Perhaps share your html as well

Comment: @TommyBs No, it wasn't a form post. It actually a POST from a plugin. The plugin will send unique id to my endpoint and I will process the file. Then after the file is complete I want to send the url to app.get

Comment: Maybe you're not actually waiting for the file processing to complete. Perhaps you need to use async/await. Can you share the processing code

Comment: @TommyBs I can't put all the code here since it's more than 500 lines. But I insert some code of what it looks like when I'm uploading file and inserting it into database. I want to send the s3 url to app.get('/:transactionid') after I insert it to db.

Comment: Do you await the upload in your post route? Without seeing the actual code in the route it’s impossible to tell. I’m guessing you’ve got promises callbacks but you’re not familiar enough with a sync code maybe (sorry I’m making an assumption here but it’s all I can think of without more code)

Comment: @TommyBs - Yes, I have await in the post route too. From the look of it, it seems like you think the code in the OP question should work? I just started learning programming 8 months ago so yes I'm not familiar with sync/async lol. 
What I did is I run it on local machine and I go to app.get. Then I use postman to post but nothing on the app.get changed. The postman however got the respond of changed page.

Comment: Now I know how you're calling it, it won't work. You're making 2 separate requests in a way that won't work. You would need to use websockets and some way to ensure it's the same user connected to the same socket in your scenario. You can't just make 2 requests from different sessions and expect them to know about each other.